# Principled reasoning about tolerances and formulas for comparing floating-point numbers?

Tags: testing, math, floating-point, precision, numerical-methods

The Python standard library contains the function [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose), which is equivalent to:

```py
abs(a - b) <= max(rtol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), atol)
```

The Numpy library likewise contains [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) and [`numpy.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html), which are equivalent to:

```py
abs(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * abs(b))
```

Neither documentation page explains why you would want to use one of these formulas over the other, or provides any principled criteria for choosing sensible absolute and relative tolerances, written above as `atol` and `rtol` respectively.

I very often end up having to use these functions in tests for my code, but I never learned any principled basis for choosing between these two formulas, or for choosing tolerances that might be appropriate to my use case.

I usually just leave the default values as-is unless I happen to know that I'm doing something that could result in a loss of numerical precision, at which point I hand-tune the tolerances until the results seem right, largely based on gut feeling and checking examples by hand. This is tedious, imperfect, and seems antithetical to the purpose of software testing, particularly [property-based testing](https://hypothesis.works/articles/what-is-property-based-testing/).

For example, I might want to assert that two different implementations of the same algorithm produce "the same" result, acknowledging that an exact equality comparison doesn't make sense.

What are **principled** techniques that I can use for choosing a sensible formula and tolerances for comparing floating point numbers? For the sake of this question, I am happy to focus on the case of testing code that uses floating-point numbers.

Comment: This is *numerical analysis*, which is an entire [field of study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis). Determining how much error can be in a final result is generally a function of intermediate data and operations and is not generally solely a function of the final result, so neither of the formulas you show can be correct for all cases. Rigorous determination of error bounds is often hard. `math.isclose`, `numpy.isclose`, and `numpy.allclose` are crude heuristics…

Comment: … What they may be good for is detecting bugs in a program—if there is some error, then a computed result is likely to be wildly different from an ideal result, so testing for “closeness” may reveal the bug. Other than that, there is little utility for testing “closeness.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you for that. For the sake of the question, I am happy to focus on the case of testing code that uses floating-point numbers. And the topic of choosing heuristics that make sense for any particular application is exactly the topic of this question!

Comment: @shadowtalker: Search "condition number of function evaluation"-that gives a principled way of to test the error of a function call. There are also numerous matrix condition numbers depending on what you are trying to achieve and what perturbations you are considering. Books: Higham's Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, Corless's Graduate Introduction to Numerical Methods.

Comment: Why restricting the use to sole numerical analysis? Wouldn't it fit domain-specific notion of closeness? Tolerance can be guided by physical considerations/engineering decisions. Dit the drone reach its waypoint? At which temperature delta shall we switch off the heater? Such tolerance shall be order of magnitude larger than additional uncertainty due to underlying floating point artifacts, that's the point of numerical analysis to bring such guaranty. Else double the precision. Or find a more robust/stable algorithm. Or relax the requirements. I guess there is no universal recipe...

Answer (score 1):

> For example, I might want to assert that two different implementations of the same algorithm produce "the same" result, acknowledging that an exact equality comparison doesn't make sense.

Consider instead of a singular true/false assessment of the "same" result, attempt to rate the algorithms same-ness on various properties.

If the assessments are within your tolerance/limits, functions are the "same".

---

Given `g(x)` and `r(x)` (the reference function).

- Absolute difference: Try `y = abs(g(x) - r(x))` for various (if not all) `x`.  What is the largest `y`?
- Relative difference: Try `y = abs((g(x) - r(x))/r(x))` for various *normal* `r(x)` (not zeroes).  What is the largest `y`?
- Relative difference: Like above with `r(x)` with sub-normal results.  Here relative difference may be far larger than with normals and so handled separately. `r(x) == +/-0.0` deserves special assessment.
- Range test/ edge cases: What is largest/smallest greatest/least `x` that "works". e.g. `y = my_exp(x)` and `exp(x)` may return infinity or 0.0 at different `x`, but are otherwise nearly the "same".
- Total ordering difference: (a favorite).  Map all non-NAN floating point values -inf to +inf to an integer: [-ORDER_N to ORDER_N] with a helper function called `total order()`. `total order(+/-0.0)` is 0.  Find the maximum difference `abs(total_order(g(x)) - total_order(r(x)))` and use that metric to determine "same"-ness.
- Various function deserve special handling.  This field of study has many further considerations.

Answer (score 1):

One question when using relative tolerance is - relative to *what*? If you want to know if 90 and 100 are "equal" with a 10% tolerance, you get different answers if you take 10% of 90 vs 10% of 100.

The standard library uses the *larger* of `a` or `b` when defining the "what" in that scenario, so it would use 10% of 100 as the tolerance.  It also uses the *larger* of that relative tolerance or the absolute tolerance as the "ultimate" tolerance.

The numpy method simbly uses `b` for the "relative" tolerance and takes the *total* of the relative and absolute tolerance as the "ultimate" tolerance.

Which is better? Neither is better or worse- they are *different* ways of establishing a tolerance. You can choose which one to use based on how *you* want to define "close enough".

The tolerances you choose are contextual as well - are you comparing lengths of lumber or the distance between circuit paths in a microprocessor? Is 1% tolerance "good enough" or do you need ultra-precise tolerance?  A tolerance too low might yield too many "false positives" depending on the application, while too high a tolerance will yield too many "false negatives" that might let some problems "slip through the cracks".

Note that the standard function is not vectorized, so if you want to use it on arrays you'll either have to use the numpy function or build a vertorized version of the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can choose the tolerances for you, they are problem dependent. Because in real-life the input data that you work on has (very) limited accuracy, be it the result of experimental measurement or of numerical computation that introduces truncation errors. So you need to know your data and understand the concepts and methods of error calculus to adjust them.

As regards the formulas, they were designed to be general-purpose, i.e. not knowing if the quantities to be compared can be strictly equal or not (when they are strictly equal, the relative error does not work). Again, this should not be a blind choice.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it doesn't really answer the question, and only confirms what I already know: I need some principled way of comparing those numbers! this question is intended to ask about what those principled ways actually are.